# Use set identities to prove that for all sets A and B

Tags: elementary-set-theory

$A \cap (B - A) = \emptyset$

$B - A = B \cap A^c$

$A \cap (B \cap A^c) = $

Then I'm lost.

Answer (score 1):

In the last line of your solution :-
By associative and commutative laws
$$A\cap(B\cap A^c)=(A\cap A^c)\cap B$$
If we want to get intersection of $A$ and $A^c$ then we get nothing by the definition and then intersection of $\phi$ and $B$ is $\phi$.

For simplicity use boollean rules. Replace $\cap$ by $\cdot$ and $\cup$ by $+$
.Then you can easily see that :-
$$A\cdot B\cdot A'=0$$
So boolean algebra is analogous to set theory.

Comment: Thanks. Good explanation, I think I was confused because I was reading $\cap$ as Union instead of intersection.

Comment: Often we are confused in set notations, because it is difficult to imagine.

Answer (score 0):

$A\cap(B\cap A^c)=A\cap(A-B)$ by (2)

$A\cap(A-B)=\emptyset$ by (1)

So, $A\cap(B\cap A^c)=\emptyset$